# Bank statement evaluation

Tags: uk, money, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image: bank statement page1/2]

[image: bank statement 2/2]

Bank statement on request withdrawn from the bank the 11/02/2019 for a balance between 08/2018 to 22/01/2019 as shown on the pictures.

My question: will they suspect that this bank statement withdrawer have something to hide inbetween the period of 22/01/2019 till 11/02/2019?

What is this evidence provided for? 
Standard visitor Visa as sponsor's bank statement.

Is the amount of money stated here well above the one that the applicant want to spend on his vacation?
Yes

When did the applicant submit his application to be evaluated at VAC?
14/02/2019

Any further request of clarification will be edited into the post

[image: please use this to assess the document that's above because this is from a tier 4(general) Visa I found for students]

Comment: Are you only intending on showing two statements? This is a great link you should read to answer a few of your questions: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105
and the suggestion there would be 3-6 months worth of statements. An important part to read is the section on Opacity "People who fear that their history make reveal a weakness will sometimes resort to an 'opacity strategy', where they submit a single statement or several statements from a broken series, or simply too few statements."

Comment: The bank statement doesnt show the last balance on the requested day because it has 2 checks rejections from bugs in the system that need to be clarified by a letter from the bank but the clarifications didnt want to show up not until the application time had passed.

Comment: @james smith This question is more or less a duplicate of one of your previous questions https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131913/little-bank-statement-anomaly-a-reason-for-a-refusal You are focussing a lot on the quality of evidence from your sponsor, however as stated in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e needing a sponsor can often be a negative rather than a positive.

Comment: I wish I can delete it as I didnt provide images of the said bank statement because it wasn't translated yet

Comment: I'd see this bank statement, I would find it very very very fishy, and not because of the gap from 22/1 to 14/2. It has transactions not listed in order. It has account management charges over many months, but not all (they're missing for September, November, December). There's also no income, so even if it shows a decent balance, the cost of the trip will result in a relatively significant chunk of that balance to be spent quite quickly.

Comment: @jcaron I provided another bank statement from a 2nd bank that shows 45k£ of deposit and I provided documents showing where the money came from plus my home plus a store,and it is missing what is missing because simply the account was stale during the periods not listed

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question: are you asking if it is a problem that your statements are few weeks old? I really do no think it is a problem, also because bank and translation take time. But do not delay too much, and you should have enough money not only for the travel and the visit, but also not to return home much poorer that you were (this is suspicious: you may not want to return).

Comment: @giacomo catenazzi i have provided PLENTY of evidence of assets, if I wished I'd literally BUY a house in London downtown it's just that I have a lot of issues with this bank in particular due to poor management, and I can't review it with the consulate because they dont have this kind of service, basically they're making rejections that can cause me a stroke because I have enough money but they explicitly say that I dont

Comment: I'm having difficult to understand, sorry. You have provided plenty of evidences, so what it is the problem? Just because one statement is not 100% correct (but not fake)? I think you are overthinking. If you have provided much documents, and this one is not so relevant, you could have not send it to them [you do no need to send all, just to provide that you have enough money (and that you will return)]. So this document will not be so relevant for the decision.

Comment: @giacomo catenazzi I need to send it because it correlates with the tax registration/ proof of employment. But if they reject the whole application because of 1 suspicion, well...

Comment: @jamessmith I personally don't understand how there could be no account management charge for most months (whether there's activity or not) and not others. Don't understand either how a dormant bank account correlates with a tax registration or proof of employment, given there's no income on that statement. But we are most probably missing the big picture here.

Comment: Trust me the issue isn't that at all, he's(the sponsor) running a couple of contracts these last months and the money keeps dropping, the issue is simply the 20 days period from 22january until 11february when this bank statement have been issued, will they judge this as a good enough reason to reject the application?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you've got a statement which doesn't show up to the date when you requested the statement and you're wondering if 'they' (the visa authorities of some nation?) will find that suspicious?

I’d say so since this is a statement you’ve gone and explicitly requested. Why wouldn’t you request up to the current date? It does seem very weird.

If this was a regular statement posted to your house then just having October, November, December could be OK; those are just the statements you had close to hand. But specifically requesting something that doesn’t go up to current?…

More worrying is that there seems to be an entire year’s worth of bank use here without any credits. Having zero income does not look good at all.

Comment: To @the other one , the applicant have checks rejections the 23th January shown in his bank statement which are technical errors made by the bank because he did pay his checks and everything is going well by now, the sponsor didnt want to show checks rejections because if he did he'd need to show a letter the bank that it was technical issues .

Comment: if the bank has made an error it doesn't matter. errors are sometimes made. i trust the bank then paid back money to fix the error and this would be shown in the statement, if not then he just has to say the bank made an error and include their contact details- when checking  bank statements most embassies call banks to check anyway

Comment: Hold up, you mean that if they'll be suspicious, they can request the bank to unveil what happened in the blurred period, find out that it's all good, and not send huge paragraph saying: you've hidden something from us therefore we refuse it, better chance next time? Also if the bank isnt in their reach, it'll be a systemic refusal nonetheless?

Comment: The embassy of Kingdomia in Otherland is used to dealing with Kingdomia visa requests. In doing this they're used to dealing with bank statements and have built up contacts in the Otherland banks to check on their validity. This is why photoshopping fake bank statements never works.  In this case...no. The 'blurred period' is information you've purposfully withheld, they'd see this as an attempt at deceit and not go out of their way to request further details, they don't care if you visit or not, you are the one who wants the visa. Best to reveal everything and let them check than leave gaps

Comment: I found a pdf online for bank statement requirement of student in tier 4 (general) Visa. Does it match my case(sponsor's bank statement)? And if it does, am I out of trouble

Comment: You mean you took your statement from the e-banking page of your bank? that should be fine. I don't think it has to be officially authenticated by the bank.

Comment: I dont know if its from e-banking page because the sponsor did physically go over the bank and requested 6 months backwards from 26th June 2018 till 22 January so the original document has the stamp of the bank but on the paper (I blurred it on purpose sorry I didnt know) has written on it : *WEB* So may be the agent of the bank did go for a bank statement from the official bank site.

Comment: The tier 4 general Visa is edited into this post above for you to check I didnt mean it was withdrawn online!